# Standardise strings in cells of a dataframe in R that appear bold

Tags: r, regex, string

Loading an **Excel** sheet into R, some strings in the cells of the dataframe appear to be bold and in a different format. For example, like so:

And when I copy **paste this string into the R console**, it appears like this:

[image: pasted into R console]

Anyone know how to fix this (revert these strings into the standard format) in R?

Want to avoid going back into **Excel** to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are actually UTF-8 encoded letters in the [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols) block in Unicode, and they don't map nicely back on to 'standard' ASCII letters in R unless you have a pre-existing mapping function such as `utf8_normalize` from the `utf8` package:

```r
library(utf8)

utf8_normalize('', map_compat = TRUE)
#> [1] "Haidara"
```

However, I would strongly recommend that you fix your Excel file before importing to avoid having to do this; it works with the example you have given us here, but there may be unwelcome surprises in converting some of your other strings.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the thorough answer! Enjoy your day.